# Categorical level to one hot encoding in python tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

If i have a categorical label like this

```
labels = [cat,dog, bird, cow]
```

now i want to convert it like one hot encoding. Is it possible by using tensorflow.
like this

```
output_label = [[1 0 0 0]
               [0 1 0 0]
               [0 0 1 0]
               [0 0 0 1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to transform your categorical data to numerical format. You could do that for example like this:

```
def categorical_to_numerical(labels):
    num_labels=[]
    for k in labels:
        if k == 'cat':
            num_labels.append(0)
        if k == 'dog':
            num_labels.append(1)
        if k == 'bird':
            num_labels.append(2)
        if k == 'cow':
            num_labels.append(3)
    return num_labels

print labels
// prints ['cat','dog', 'bird', 'cow', 'dog', 'bird'] 
print categorical_to_numerical(labels)
// prints [0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

Now you can easily use a tensorflow built-in function called `tf.one_hot`:

```
indices = categorical_to_numerical(labels)
detph = 4 // because you have four categories 
one_hot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices, depth)
```

Read more about `tf.one_hot` [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot).